# How can I import pre-generated SVG patterns using SVG.js?

Tags: svg.js

I want to leverage existing libraries of SVG patterns (e.g., https://philiprogers.com/svgpatterns) without having to reconstruct them. But I'm struggling to understand how to import raw SVG strings. The docs show how to place something on the canvas, but after an hour in JSFiddle, I just can't get it to load a pattern. Any help would be appreciated.

### Final Answer

- Find the pattern you want. (This example uses two from Rogers's library.)
- Copy the complete SVG code and drop that in the `draw.defs().svg(...)` line mentioned in the answer.
- Wrap the `<svg>` tag in a `<pattern>` tag that contains the properties `id`, `patternUnits`, `height`, and `width`.

Final code:

```js
// initialize SVG.js
var draw = SVG('drawing')

// Define the patterns. Multiple `svg()` calls don't clobber each other.
draw.defs().svg("<pattern id='chevrons' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse' width='60' height='30'><svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='60' height='30'><defs><rect id='r' width='30' height='15' fill='white' stroke-width='2.5' stroke='black'/><g id='p'><use xlink:href='#r'/><use y='15' xlink:href='#r'/><use y='30' xlink:href='#r'/><use y='45' xlink:href='#r'/></g></defs><use xlink:href='#p' transform='translate(0 -25) skewY(40)'/><use xlink:href='#p' transform='translate(30 0) skewY(-40)'/></svg></pattern>")
draw.defs().svg("<pattern id='microbial' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse' width='20' height=20><svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='20' height='20'><rect width='40' height='40' fill='white'/><circle r='9.2' stroke-width='1' stroke='black' fill='none'/><circle cy='18.4' r='9.2' stroke-width='1px' stroke='black' fill='none'/><circle cx='18.4' cy='18.4' r='9.2' stroke-width='1' stroke='black' fill='none'/></svg></pattern")

// Load the pattern by id
var pattern = SVG.get('chevrons')

// Apply it
draw.circle(100).move(100, 50).stroke({width: 1, color: "black"}).fill(pattern)
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fr84e5g9/.

Thanks, @fuzzyma!

Comment: Can you please include an example of how you're trying to do this?  The site you linked to is just using plain old `data:image` urls, which you can treat as you would any image; is that not what you mean by "importing raw SVG strings"?

Comment: There you go. I have a library that is generating SVG images on the fly based on JSON data provided by a user. I want to have a library of patterns that can be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### svg.js v2

When you import an svg string with the `svg()` method you dont get back the element you imported. Just imagine you imported 2 rects like this:

```
draw.svg('<rect/><rect/>')
```

You cant get back 2 rectangles. Thats why you get back the the element on which you called the svg method which is `draw` in your example.

So, first import the pattern into the defs:

```
draw.defs().svg('<pattern id="someId">....</pattern>')
```

Then retrieve it over its id:

```
var pattern = SVG.get('someId')
```

And use fill

```
rect.fill(pattern)
```

Please make sure, that you take a look into the generated code. You can simply do that when opening the developer tools of every browser. You would see fast enough whats generated there and how to use it.

#### svg.js v3

With version 3 the import results in a bit different code but the code should still work. However, to retrieve an element with a specific id use `SVG('#someId')` or similar css selectors.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this first thing when I get home tonight and report back.

Comment: What do you mean by "look into the generated code"? You mean look at the SVG code the examples generate? The problem there is that there are no examples in the import/export section of the docs :( Once I get my code working, I may make some PRs against the docs.

Comment: yes and no, you righclick on your website and choose "inspect element" and then you look into the source code of the site. You can do that with your examples too. They do something. Look up what they do and decide how to go from there. You would see, that the import is successful and could decide how to use what you just imported

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for your time. Once I get the pattern code working, I'll come back and mark this as answered.